# Python - Make sure string is converted to correct Float

Tags: python, regex

I have possible strings of prices like:

```
20.99, 20, 20.12
```

Sometimes the string could be sent to me wrongly by the user to something like this:

```
20.99.0, 20.0.0
```

These should be converted back to :

```
20.99, 20
```

So basically removing anything from the 2nd . if there is one.

*Just to be clear, they would be alone, one at a time, so just one price in one string*

Any nice one liner ideas?

Comment: Is it always a trailing `.0`?

Comment: No, could be any thing, 19.99.32 etc

Comment: @Harry: So, if it is `19.99.32` your desired output is `19.99` right ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For a one-liner, you can use `.split()` and `.join()`:

```
>>> '.'.join('20.99.0'.split('.')[:2])
'20.99'
>>> '.'.join('20.99.1231.23'.split('.')[:2])
'20.99'
>>> '.'.join('20.99'.split('.')[:2])
'20.99'
>>> '.'.join('20'.split('.')[:2])
'20'
```

Comment: this will discard everything after the second `.`

Comment: Isn't that the intended behavior? As the OP said, *Just to be clear, they would be alone, one at a time, so just one price in one string*

Comment: This is perfect, and I like the way you did it. The others are correct to, but yours seems simpler! thanks

Comment: @Harry: So, why not atleast upvote other's for making an attempt :D

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this

```
>>> s = '20.99.0, 20.0.0'
>>> s.split(',')
['20.99.0', ' 20.0.0']
>>> map(lambda x: x[:x.find('.',x.find('.')+1)], s.split(','))
['20.99', ' 20.0']
```

Look at the inner expression of find. I am finding the first '.' and incrementing by 1 and then find the next '.' and leaving everything from that in the string slice operation.

Comment: +1. I like that this doesn't create so many temporary objects. Why not go with a LC though `[float(x[:x.find('.', x.find('.') + 1)]) for x in s.split(',')]`

Answer (score 2):

*Edit:* Note that this solution will not discard everything from the second decimal point, but discard only the second point and keep additional digits. If you want to discard all digits, you could use e.g. @Blender's solution

It only qualifies as a one-liner if two instructions per line with a `;` count, but here's what I came up with:

```
>>> x = "20.99.1234"
>>> s = x.split("."); x = s[0] + "." +  "".join(s[1:])
>>> x
20.991234
```

It should be a little faster than scanning through the string multiple times, though. For a performance cost, you can do this:

```
>>> x = x.split(".")[0] + "." +  "".join(x.split(".")[1:])
```

For a whole list:

```
>>> def numify(x):
>>>     s = x.split(".")
>>>     return float( s[0] + "." + "".join(s[1:]))
>>> x = ["123.4.56", "12.34", "12345.6.7.8.9"]
>>> [ numify(f) for f in x ] 
[123.456, 12.34, 12345.6789]
```

Comment: You can get pretty crazy with one-liners: `'.'.join(map(lambda x: x.replace('.', ''), '20.99.1234'.partition('.')[::2]))`

Comment: Are you sure this is the OP's intended behaviour because from his question it seems that he want to discard everything after the second `.(decimal)` or may be I am wrong.

Comment: I'm not sure. Taking OP literally, _anything_ from the second `.` should be discarded, but this solution made more sense to me. I'll update my answer to stress that the digits after the second `.` will be included.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a regex based solution and your intended behaviour is to discard everthing after the second `.(decimal)` than

```
>>> st = "20.99.123"
>>> string_decimal = re.findall(r'\d+\.\d+',st)
>>> float(''.join(string_decimal))
20.99
```

Comment: `string` is the name of a module in Python. I suggest you try a different name for your variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = '20.99, 20, 20.99.23'
>>> ','.join(x if x.count('.') in [1,0] else x[:x.rfind('.')] for x in s.split(','))
'20.99, 20, 20.99'
```